# Eclipse cannot debug. Please help I tried everything

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging

Whenever I try to open the debug perspective, I get this message and the problem is that it **disappears** immediately before I can even check deny or allow. I can run the program, but I cannot debug.

> [image]

I run **OS X 10.8.5**

Things I tried, but all failed

1. I have tried to uninstall and install Eclipse, but that did nothing.
2. I tried adding Eclipse to my firewall exceptions and checked "allow incoming connection" in Security and Privacy, but that did nothing.
3. I have tried following the instructions mentioned [here](http://silvanolte.com/blog/2011/01/18/do-you-want-the-application-to-accept-incoming-network-connections/).

But no help at all.

Comment: I also get the message but it stays until I press Allow. I am using Java 7 on OS X 10.9.1 (but 10.8 was the same). Is this Java 6 or 7?

Comment: I checked Security and Preferences and it says 'Version 7 Update 45 (build 1.7.0_45-b18)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "security" tempering I didn't saw in the link you reference in your question is:

- removing Eclipse from the firewall list of apps
- removing Eclipse from the **[`plist` files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/3274)**.

> A `plist` is a special kind of text file that contains properties the application and other resources, typically the OS, use to retain and reuse information needed to run the application.
>   `plist` is a file type and has many uses, typically storing user preferences, but, essentially, it is an XML file. You can look to see if there are any caches, which are typically plist files, for the applications in question in `/Library/Caches` and `/System/Library/Caches`.

Comment: If I remove Eclipse from the firewall list, it still doesn't work. I searched for "eclipse.plist" and nothing came up in spotlight.

Comment: @sidht it could be as in `com.company.appname.plist`, so try a search like '`*eclipse*.plist*`'

Comment: You mean literally " *eclipse*.plist* "? I did that and nothing came up again.Sorry I am not very good with computers.

Comment: @sidht I mean that the plist filename might not start with eclipse, but have eclipse in it.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what to search then. If it does not contain the word 'eclipse', how do I know it is the right one to delete?

Comment: @sidht maybe do a content search on all plist file, to see if one contains the word eclipse? But my previous comment was about the *name* of the file, and the fact that "eclipse" could be in the *middle* of that name.

Comment: Here is what I did. (1) I typed in "plist" in spotlight, opened a folder, and that opened up a big list of "info.plist" and "version.plist" files (2) typed in ".eclipse.plist" (with a dot in front of eclipse) and go nothing (3) Went into library cache manually and only found com.apple. or com.adobe plist files (4) went into eclipse folder and found an "archive.xml", is that the one?

Comment: @sidht I wouldn't know for sure, having no Mac to test it out. But that one was lead you didn't explore yet.

Comment: Figured out what thep problem was. I'll give bounty nonetheless.

Comment: @sidht great! What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Checking on that particular error message, it seems to be caused by issues with the firewall configuration. I am not sure if it will help, but I would verify that the program is allowed to access your network. Check in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options. You should be able to allow your app to access the network from there. Hope this helps!